# Using __kindof with non-collection types

Tags: objective-c

Xcode 7 [added](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html) the `__kindof` decorator to object declarations:

> **KindOf.** Objects declared as `__kindof` types express "some kind of X" to the compiler and can be used within generic parameters to constrain types to a particular class or its subclasses. Using `__kindof` allows constraints to be more flexible than an explicit class, and more explicit than just using `id`.

The most obvious use case for `__kindof` is with collection types to explicitly state what kind of objects will be in a particular collection.  From the `UIStackView` header:

```
- (instancetype)initWithArrangedSubviews:(NSArray<__kindof UIView *> *)views; // Adds views as subviews of the receiver.
@property(nonatomic,readonly,copy) NSArray<__kindof UIView *> *arrangedSubviews;
```

This explicitly states that each `NSArray` will contain objects that are or inherit from `UIView`.

But there are some cases where `__kindof` is used on a non-collection typed object, such as in the `UIStoryboardSegue` header:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) __kindof UIViewController *sourceViewController;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) __kindof UIViewController *destinationViewController;
```

What does the `__kindof` decorator change on non-collection-type objects?

Comment: It's a question about Objective-C. The IDE you are using doesn't really pertain to your question.

Comment: @rmaddy is there a better tag I should use for something for an object decorator that only works in a specific version of an IDE or compiler?  Or do you feel that the [tag:objective-c] tag is sufficient for this question.

Comment: I see no reason for any other tags. The title and question make it all clear enough. It won't be any more visible with additional tags.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks @rmaddy.

Comment: My guess is that someone doesn't understand that is it perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question as long as both the answer and the question follow all the normal guidelines (which these do).

Comment: Another example is CoreData's - (nullable __kindof NSManagedObject *)existingObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID*)objectID which is because the method is in NSManagedObjectContext so can't use instancetype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious case is when casting types:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
// SomeViewController inherits from UIViewController
SomeViewController *someViewController = vc; // Warning: Incompatible pointer type initializing 'SomeViewController *' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *'

__kindof UIViewController *otherVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
SomeViewController *someVC = otherVC; // no warning
```

This is why in a `UIViewController`'s `prepareForSegue` method, casting `segue.destinationViewController` to another `UIViewController` subclass does not show a warning:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    SomeViewController *someVC = segue.destinationViewController; // no warning
    // ...
}
```