# Why can such code be compiled? Call popToRootViewControllerAnimated in iOS UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question about iOS development. Why can this be compile?

```
__kindof UIViewController *selectedViewController;
[selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: It is compiled successful

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629886/using-kindof-with-non-collection-types

Answer (score 2):

The use of `__kindof` means that the compiler can assume, in this case, that `selectedViewController` will be of type `UIViewController` or any subclass that has `UIViewController` in its hierarchy.

`popToRootViewController` is a method of `UINavigationController`. Since `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, the compiler says:

> OK, I'm going to assume you know what you are doing and let you call a method I know to be from a subclass of UIViewController.

This is similar to using a cast:

```
UIViewController *selectedViewController;
[(UINavigationController *)selectedViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You are telling the compiler to trust you.

But of course, in both cases, if at runtime the variable isn't actually a `UINavigationController`, then the code will crash at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController can't pop controller, UINavigationController does.

Comment: Yes, however, `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

Comment: But it is indeed a successful compilation.

Answer (score -1):

UINavigationController has rootViewController property and it can have multiple view controllers so you can reach to first view controller by using popToRootViewController. You can use following code for swift version.

```
    viewController.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```